# Issue in converting a Docker image to a Kubernetes Deployment File

Tags: docker, kubernetes, apache-kafka

I am trying to convert my dockerised application for testing a Kafka functionality, to a Kubernetes deployment file.

The docker command for execution of the container which is working as expected is:

```
docker run --name consumer-1 --network="host" -dt 56d57e1538d3 pizzaapp_multiconsumer1.py bash
```

However, when converting it to the below Kubernetes deployment file and executing it, I am getting a CrashLoopBackOff error on the pods.

```
spec:
      hostNetwork: true
      containers:
      - name: kafka-consumer
        image: bhuvidockerhub/kafkaproject:v1.0
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        args: ["pizzaapp_multiconsumer1.py", "bash"]
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: regcred
```

On checking the logs of the failed pods I am seeing this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "//pizzaapp_multiconsumer1.py", line 12, in <module>
    multiconsume_pizza_messages()
  File "/testconsumer1.py", line 14, in multiconsume_pizza_messages
    kafka_admin_client: KafkaAdminClient = KafkaAdminClient(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kafka/admin/client.py", line 208, in __init__
    self._client = KafkaClient(metrics=self._metrics,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kafka/client_async.py", line 244, in __init__
    self.config['api_version'] = self.check_version(timeout=check_timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kafka/client_async.py", line 900, in check_version
    raise Errors.NoBrokersAvailable()
kafka.errors.NoBrokersAvailable: NoBrokersAvailable
```

But the broker container is already up and running

```
my-cluster-with-metrics-entity-operator-7d8894b79f-99fwt   3/3     Running   181        27d
my-cluster-with-metrics-kafka-0                            1/1     Running   57         19d
my-cluster-with-metrics-kafka-1                            1/1     Running   5          19h
my-cluster-with-metrics-kafka-2                            1/1     Running   0          27m
my-cluster-with-metrics-kafka-exporter-568968bd5c-mrg7f    1/1     Running   108        27d
```

and the corresponding services are also there

```
my-cluster-with-metrics-kafka-bootstrap            ClusterIP   10.98.78.168     <none>        9091/TCP,9100/TCP                     27d
my-cluster-with-metrics-kafka-brokers              ClusterIP   None             <none>        9090/TCP,9091/TCP,9100/TCP            27d
my-cluster-with-metrics-kafka-external-0           NodePort    10.110.196.75    <none>        9099:30461/TCP                        27d
my-cluster-with-metrics-kafka-external-1           NodePort    10.107.225.187   <none>        9099:32310/TCP                        27d
my-cluster-with-metrics-kafka-external-2           NodePort    10.103.99.151    <none>        9099:31950/TCP                        27d
my-cluster-with-metrics-kafka-external-bootstrap   NodePort    10.98.131.151    <none>        9099:31248/TCP                        27d
```

And I have port forwarded the svc port so that the brokers can be found:

```
kubectl port-forward svc/my-cluster-with-metrics-kafka-external-bootstrap  9099:9099 -n kafka
```

And post this when I run the docker command it executes, as expected.

But in K8s even after adding the bash in the args and trying, it still gives no brokers available.

Can anyone suggest what changes shall I try out in the deployment file, so that it works exactly as the successful docker command run as stated above?

Comment: Unclear what bootstrap address you gave, but you should be using k8s service discovery to communicate with the internal advertised services, ideally given as an environment variable to your client deployment, and not use `--network="host"` or need to use port forwarding

Comment: @OneCricketeer Actually the bootstrap address that I gave in my application was [localhost:9099], as the application is being run from inside a minikube cluster that is installed on an EC2 ubuntu machine. This is the reason I am using port forwarding and --network="host" to run and expose that particular port. I have two broker services name, out of which external bootstrap is the one which is port forwarded at the minute - my-cluster-with-metrics-kafka-external-bootstrap. How can I use this service inside my deployment file such that the localhost from within the K8s is accessible.

Comment: 1) If your app is deployed in k8s, then you don't need kafka port forwarding since there is nothing to expose outside the cluster 2) `localhost` refers to the pod's container itself, so that clearly needs to be completely replaced. I'd suggest going over some Kubernetes specific resources for how service discovery and network communication between pods works, since this problem is not related to Kafka

Comment: Thanks, @OneCricketeer I actually tried this logic out, replaced the localhost completely with the external-bootstrap service IP and was able to run the producer and consumer successfully now.  Issue resolved.

Comment: Feel free to answer your own question below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an application is deployed in K8s, then we don't need port forwarding since there is nothing to expose outside the cluster. When we run things inside K8s, we normally do not access things using localhost. Localhost refers to the pod's container itself.
Therefore, to resolve the above issue, completely removed the localhost reference from the bootstrap server. This was then replaced with the external bootstrap service IP [10.X.X.X:9099] and then executed the K8s deployment file. Following which the producer and consumer pods came up successfully, and this resolved the issue.

Comment: Might also be useful to show your full Kafka and deployment specs